# If a value in a range is null, do nothing. Else execute this. Boggles my mind

Tags: excel, vba

I need to iterate through three columns and format all of those columns as text.  If a cell in that column is null, do nothing.  Else execute code that will add a append a leading zero to a corresponding value from a "find array" and print that value in the cell.

I have a working set of find and replace code.  I have a working set of text formatting code that will add a leading zero.  What I can't do is refine this to only affect cells in the range that contain a value.  I know it is some "If" or "For" statement or a combination of both.  I just can't nail it down.

```
Sub dis_code_replace()
'
' dis_code_replace Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+d
'

    Windows("PERSONAL.XLSB").Visible = True

'Define Variables
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim privplacedrange
Dim primdis As Range
Dim secdis As Range
Dim thirddis As Range
Dim endrange As Range
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim alist As Variant
Dim cel As Range
Dim PrimaryDisability As Range
Dim SecondaryDisability As Range
Dim TertiaryDisability As Range

'Set Variables
Set primdis = ActiveSheet.Range("v2:v1000")
Set secdis = ActiveSheet.Range("z2:z1000")
Set timeinregularearlychildhoodsetting = ActiveSheet.Range("dp:dp")
Set specialedinregularearlychildhoodsetting = ActiveSheet.Range("dq:dq")
Set thirddis = ActiveSheet.Range("AD2:AD1000")
Set endrange = ActiveSheet.Range("dp:dq")
Set privplacedrange = ActiveSheet.Range("S:S")
Set PrimaryDisability = ActiveSheet.Range("V:V")
Set SecondaryDisability = ActiveSheet.Range("Z:Z")
Set TertiaryDisability = ActiveSheet.Range("AD:AD")
fndList = Array("MD", "OI", "VI", "HI", "SLD", "ED", "SLI", "OHI", "DB", "AUT", "TBI", "504", "DD", "ID")
rplcList = Array("03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "19")
alistfind = Array("N", "Y")
alistreplace = Array("0", "1")
pdfindlist = Array("N", "Y")
pdreplacelist = Array("0", "1")





 'Replace the Y and N values in the Privately Placed column with Powerschool appropriate 1 and 0's
For x = LBound(pdfindlist) To UBound(pdreplacelist)
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        privplacedrange.Replace what:=pdfindlist(x), replacement:=pdreplacelist(x), _
          lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          searchformat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht

    Next x

'Replace the Y and N values in the last two columns with Powerschool appropriate 1 and 0's
For x = LBound(alistfind) To UBound(alistfind)
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        endrange.Replace what:=alistfind(x), replacement:=alistreplace(x), _
          lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          searchformat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht

    Next x

'Replace alphabetical disability codes with Powerschool appropriate numerical values
  For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
      For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        primdis.Replace what:=fndList(x), replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          searchformat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        secdis.Replace what:=fndList(x), replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          searchformat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        thirddis.Replace what:=fndList(x), replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          searchformat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
      Next sht

  Next x

  'Apply a leading zero so Powerschool will recognize the appropriate disability code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    PrimaryDisability.NumberFormat = "@"
    For Each cel In PrimaryDisability.Cells
    cel.Value = "0" & cel.Value
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    SecondaryDisability.NumberFormat = "@"
    For Each cel In SecondaryDisability.Cells
    cel.Value = "0" & cel.Value
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    TertiaryDisability.NumberFormat = "@"
    For Each cel In TertiaryDisability.Cells
    cel.Value = "0" & cel.Value
    Next

 'Delete un-needed columns
 Range("b:g,i:n,p:r,t:u,w:x,ai:do").EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

If I run this against my spreadsheet, The alpha characters are successfully replaced with a leading zero and the corresponding number.  It does not, however, ignore cells that are null.  I need it to ignore null cells.  It also should not append a leading zero where the replacing number is two digits or more.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean to check for [IsEmpty()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isempty-function)?

Comment: Couldn't you use formatting to achieve the same thing (without using VBA)?